# Template compile-time errors when compiling list iterators with ARM GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compilation, syntax-error

This code gives me many headaches when compiling under GCC ARM. I am using it fine with MSVC++ compiler 2010. I get compile errors like:

Error  1   error : expected ';' before 'i' C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\droplets\source\MultiList.h   62

Why won't my templated code compile using GCC?

```
#ifndef MULTILIST_H
#define MULTILIST_H

#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

/*
 A list of lists
 */
template <typename E> 
class MultiList {

protected:
    list<list<E>*>      m_lists;
    list<E>             *m_pCurrList;

public:

    MultiList();
    ~MultiList();
    /*
    Starts a new list internally, given the first element
    */
    void BeginNewList(E firstElement);

    /*
    Adds an element to the current list
    */
    void AddElement(E newElement);

    /*
    Removes a given element from it's place in one of the lists,
    splitting that list into two lists internally.
    */
    void RemoveElement(E element);

    /*
    Returns a list of all element lists
    */
    list<list<E>*> *GetLists() {
        return &m_lists;
    };

    /*
    Return the list that's currently being populated with AddElement()
    */
    list<E>* GetCurrentList() {
        return m_pCurrList;
    };

};

template<typename E>
MultiList<E>::MultiList() {
    m_pCurrList = NULL;
}

template<typename E>
MultiList<E>::~MultiList() {
    for(list<list<E>*>::iterator i = m_lists.begin(); i != m_lists.end(); i++) {
        list<E>::iterator j;
        for(j = (*i)->begin(); j != (*i)->end(); j++) {
            SDELETE(*j)
        }
        SDELETE(*i)
    }
}

/*
Starts a new list internally, given the first element
*/
template<typename E>
void MultiList<E>::BeginNewList(E firstElement) {
    list<E> *newlist = new(list<E>);
    newlist->push_back(firstElement);
    m_lists.push_back(newlist);
    m_pCurrList = newlist;
}

/*
Adds an element to the current list
*/
template<typename E>
void MultiList<E>::AddElement(E newElement) {
    m_pCurrList->push_back(newElement);
}

/*
Removes a given element from it's place in one of the lists,
splitting that list into two lists internally.
*/
template<typename E>
void MultiList<E>::RemoveElement(E element) {
    list<E>* found = NULL;
    list<E>::iterator foundIT = NULL;

    // find which list 'element' is in
    for(list<list<E>*>::iterator i = m_lists.begin(); i != m_lists.end(); i++) {
        list<E>::iterator j;
        for(j = (*i)->begin(); j != (*i)->end(); j++) {
            E listElement = (*j);
            if(listElement == element) {
                found = (*i);
                foundIT = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j != (*i)->end()) break; // we breaked out of the inner loop
    }
    // now erase it and split the list
    if (found) {
        list<E>::iterator next = found->erase(foundIT);
        list<E> *newlist = new(list<E>);
        m_lists.push_back(newlist);
        newlist->splice(newlist->begin(), *found, next, found->end());
        SDELETE(element)
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Nice code. What's your question?

Comment: Hi guys, just updated with my question :) I'm really confused as this is working code, porting it to GCC/cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't compile because it is chock full o'errors:

```
g++ -Wall /tmp/junk.c
/tmp/junk.c: In destructor ‘MultiList<E>::~MultiList()’:
/tmp/junk.c:62:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<std::list<E>*>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<std::list<E>*>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:62:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
/tmp/junk.c:62:55: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:63:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<E>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<E>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:63:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘j’
/tmp/junk.c:64:13: error: ‘j’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:65:23: error: there are no arguments to ‘SDELETE’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘SDELETE’ must be available
/tmp/junk.c:65:23: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
/tmp/junk.c:66:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
/tmp/junk.c:67:19: error: there are no arguments to ‘SDELETE’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘SDELETE’ must be available
/tmp/junk.c:68:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
/tmp/junk.c: In member function ‘void MultiList<E>::RemoveElement(E)’:
/tmp/junk.c:97:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<E>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<E>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:97:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘foundIT’
/tmp/junk.c:100:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<std::list<E>*>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<std::list<E>*>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:100:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i’
/tmp/junk.c:100:55: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:101:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<E>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<E>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:101:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘j’
/tmp/junk.c:102:13: error: ‘j’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:106:17: error: ‘foundIT’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:114:9: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::list<E>::iterator’ because ‘std::list<E>’ is a dependent scope
/tmp/junk.c:114:27: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘next’
/tmp/junk.c:117:51: error: ‘next’ was not declared in this scope
/tmp/junk.c:119:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
```

Use `-Wall` and understand what its complaints are. A better question might be why did MSVC **not** complain?

Comment: Ah awesome, I didn't know about -Wall, wow you're right there are a lot of ambiguities. Okay I'll have a stab at making these corrections and let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Great, got it working. Wherever I used ::iterator on a type defined using E, I needed to tell the compiler it was a type by inserting 'typename' before that declaration, because it didn't know and obviously didn't want to assume.

Comment: @Ryan: help save the world (or at least StackOverflow) edit your question to incorporate what you learned. You can also create an answer to your own question and accept that instead (self-answers are good for SO).